# Upload image( creating preview thumbnail) at the area where we click in dropzone ( dropzone.js)

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am using dropznone.js for image upload feature, I want to know whether we can able to upload the image ( creating the preview thumbnail ) at the area where we click.

Here is the preview 
[image]

Comment: Yeah sure, why not.

Comment: how to achieve this @C14L , I searched the documentation. There is no details regarding this topic